# Error: Text content does not match server-rendered HTML. I get an error when checking if the user is logged in

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I use the isAuth variable to check if the user is logged in in my Header.js file and get the error "Text content does not match server-rendered HTML." I import the isAuth variable from the authContext.js file

Here is part of my Header.js file:
`

```
{isAuth ? (
     <StyledLink href="/" onClick={onClick}>Logout</StyledLink>
) : (
     <StyledLink href='/login' className={pathname.includes('/login') ? 'active' :      ''}>Login</StyledLink>
)}
```

`

Here is AuthContext.js file:

I tried adding different functions and rewriting the code, but nothing helped

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import storage from 'local-storage-fallback';

const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const storedIsAuth = storage.getItem('isAuth') === 'true';
  const [isAuth, setIsAuth] = useState(storedIsAuth);

  const setAuthStatus = (authStatus) => {
    if (authStatus) {
      storage.setItem('isAuth', 'true');
    } else {
      storage.removeItem('isAuth');
    }
    setIsAuth(authStatus);
  };

  const contextValue = {
    isAuth,
    setAuthStatus,
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);
```